# Tomcat8 not deploying war file

Tags: apache, tomcat8, system-administration

I am setting up a new server in centos7 with oracle java 7 and already tried java 8 too.

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

I have tried tomcat 7 also both give the same result.  I believe this is the fault of java. The war file I kept in webapps doesn't deploy at all. I have tried deploying through manager-GUI even that doesn't work. I have included logs of tomcat.

```
[root@localhost apache-tomcat-8.5.40]# logs
14-May-2019 05:32:41.787 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.40/webapps/docs] has finished in [226] ms
14-May-2019 05:32:41.788 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.40/webapps/examples]
14-May-2019 05:32:42.047 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.40/webapps/examples] has finished in [260] ms
14-May-2019 05:32:42.047 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.40/webapps/host-manager]
14-May-2019 05:32:42.071 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.40/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [23] ms
14-May-2019 05:32:42.071 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.40/webapps/manager]
14-May-2019 05:32:42.091 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.40/webapps/manager] has finished in [20] ms
14-May-2019 05:32:42.105 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
14-May-2019 05:32:42.113 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
14-May-2019 05:32:42.114 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 659 ms
```

I believe this is the fault of the Java but not sure .. I need help solving this problem. Thanks in advance

[image: image from browser]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse to run tomcat server.

Double click on the tomcat server in eclipse.

In server location tab, select use tomcat installation(takes control of Tomcat location)

save and restart the server.

Hope this will help you

Comment: No sir, I am not using eclipse, i am working on Grails. Setting up centos server to deploy war file

Comment: Its look like the server has not started properly. Make sure the configurations are done properly.

Comment: Thankyou @T.H.E. Tech Savvy but finally solved the problem. turns out the war file was not properly compiled :D